# AS3: Accessing a dynamicaly added child from another dynamicaly added child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, actionscript, movieclip

So heres my question, I have a button on the stage that adds a MC called "fadeL" and "PDF1"

Quick note: "fadeL" and "PDF1" are instances of "fadeMC" and "PDFwindow" heres the code for them:

```
var fadeL:fadeMC = new fadeMC();
this.addChild(fadeL);
fadeL.x = 0;
fadeL.y = 0;   

var PDF1:PDFwindow = new PDFwindow();
this.addChild(PDF1);
PDF1.x = 30;
PDF1.y = 130;
```

Within PDF1 is another MC called "PDFviewer" which contains a button called closeBtn

Here is the actionscript for that button:

```
var container:DisplayObjectContainer = stage.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
var mc:MovieClip = container.getChildByName("fadeL") as MovieClip;
mc.gotoAndStop(12);
```

So basicly Im trying to tell "fadeL" to start playing at frame 12 (which ultimately makes it fade off the screen)

but here is the error I get when closeBtn is pressed:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at NovartisTable_fla::PDFviewer_4/closeTap()[NovartisTable_fla.PDFviewer_4::frame1:9]

Any suggestions here? been looking around for other ways to tackle this but all have failed me

-Todd

Comment: You might have to share more of your code, to get help on that.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually grabbing a reference to `fadeL` when you called `stage.getChildAt(0)` (assuming the code you are showing is the only time you're adding items to the display list).

Change your button handler to this:

```
var mc:MovieClip = stage.getChildAt(0) as DisplayObjectContainer;
mc.gotoAndStop(12);
```

Failing that, I would give `fadeL` an actual `name` so you can do the following:

```
fadeL.name = "fadeL";
...
var mc:MovieClip = stage.getChildByName("fadeL") as MovieClip;
mc.gotoAndStop(12);
```